# Eloquent Multiple Join With Where Clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to join the user table with the attendance_user and attendance_supervisor table where the location id is equal to a specific value however currently the results that i am being returned doesnt seem to take into consideration the where clause.

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrongly?

```
$new_attendance_user = AttendanceUser::join('users','users.id','=','attendance_users,user_id')
->join('attendance_supervisors','users.id','=','attendance_supervisors.user_id')
->groupby('user_id')
->where('function($query)uses($location){
$query->where('attendance_supervisors.atttendance_location','=','$location')
->orWhere('attendance_users.atttendance_location','=','$location');
}
->get()
```

User Table

```
class User extends Eloquent{

    public function attendance_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('attendance_user');
    }
    public function attendance_supervisors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('attendance_supervisor');
    }
```

}

Attendance_user

```
    class AttendanceUser extends Eloquent{
    
        public function userBelongsToUser()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }
  }
```

Attendance_supervisor

```
    class AttendanceSupervisor extends Eloquent{
    
        public function supBelongsToUser()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }
  }
```

Comment: can you post the scripts to create your tables as well as populate them with data and also the result set you are getting back along with an example of what you want the result set to look like?

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: try adding the groupBy() method after the get() method